# firebase deploy: error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'path_to_project/functions'

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I need to deploy my project to firebase, I need to deploy some functions too: the command firebase deploy starts working correctly but ends with the error in the title, I run npm install in the main directory and in the functions directory too, but the error is the same.

Comment: Can you share your `firebase.json` file with use. It should be in your root folder.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/XX8x7WQs

Comment: Could you try to add to the `functions` part in the json the path to your functions fodler like `"source":"functions"`. And yould you share the complete log when you deploy. Also the parts before the error.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/wR6MrBDb

Comment: It looks like your `functions` folder can't be found. But the data you send is not your `firebase.json` file. Could you share that with me. It's just the conifguration for firebase where stuff is. Could you also make a screenshot of your root folder.

Comment: my firebase.json and my root folderhttps://pastebin.com/KnLqr7UQ this is my firebase.json, sorry I do not know how to send the screenshot, I can send you the schema. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change your `firebase.json` to:

```js
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "source": "functions",
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "www",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}
```

Comment: it is still  the same

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your project root file structure?

Comment: [![root file structure][1]] [1]: https://pasteboard.co/K2tLzSH.png

Comment: Can you try this `rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clear && npm install` in your functions folder

Comment: Could you share also some of your functions code?